# Passing ID in template driven Angular form

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created an Angular form following this article (http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/):

```
<div *ngFor="let data of somevar.records">
  <form #abc_form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(abc_form.value)">
    {{data.id}}    // prints 5
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value={{data.id}} ngModel>
    <input type="radio" name="name" value={{data.id}} ngModel>

    <div class="submit-button">
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The **data** hash in component looks something like:

```
somevar = {records: [{id: 5}, {id: 6}]}
```

Here, when I directly interpolate `data.id` in view it prints 5 in UI. But, when I try assigning it as a value to an hidden input field, it isn't present. Hence, upon form submission **ID** parameter is not present.

What is wrong here? What is the correct way to pass **ID** then?

**EDIT**

I also tried:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" [value]="data.id" ngModel>
```

**NOTE** The value gets assigned to the hidden field when I remove **ngModel**:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" [value]="data.id">
```

OR

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value={{data.id}}>
```

Both the above works and creates hidden inputs with values assigned. But, it's not part of **ngModel** anymore

Comment: can you try using this `[ngModel] = "data.id"` ?

Comment: Yes that works, can you please explain?

Comment: @RahulSingh Can you explain why the radio element works, but input element doesn't. http://plnkr.co/edit/GGU7imcBCCJFWVsGgR89?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ngModel` and `value`, you can use `[ngModel]` to bind the value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" [ngModel]="data.id">
```

Now it will be part of your form.

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/oF5lFSbMbyltB0Mgi6hi?p=preview

Comment: I have edited my code. I also have `<input type="radio" name="name" value={{data.id}} ngModel>` whick works, but it doesn't work as part of hidden field?

Answer (score 2):

When creating multiple ngModel controls inside ngFor loop each control and name must be unique

You can try this :

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of somevar.records;let index = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
  <form #abc_form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(abc_form.value)">
    {{data.id}}    // prints 5
    <input name="id_{{index}}" type="hidden" [ngModel]=data[index].id>

    <div class="submit-button">
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Good Suggestion to use index

Answer (score 0):

To use the data binding you need to change your hidden input to this:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" [value]=data.id>
```

Remove the `ngModel` because it the data binding via `[value]` and the `ngModel` could interfere with each other.

**EDIT**
My bad, of course you have to remove the curly braces too.

Comment: Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{data.id}}]

Comment: `{{}}` never goes together with `[prop]="..."` or `(event)="..."` @Abhi

Comment: @RahulSingh Correct!!! That's one of the tires I posted in the question.

Comment: remove the braces and try the same

Comment: @RahulSingh Still no luck

Comment: @MaKobi I'm getting problem while using **ngModel** as I mentioned in the question